# Why am getting this error in command-line when running python project?

Tags: python, command-line

I am very green to this process so please bear with me.  I am in a Computer Science class where we have to run python code from the command line to extract tweets from Twitter.  I ran the provided code and the program ran for about 30 minutes and just stopped on its own and gave an error which I didn't capture at the time.  I closed out the command screen and restated the process. It no longer runs and just spits out the following error.  I have no idea what any of this means so I am not sure what to do to resolve it.  I tried rebooting and starting again, but I am getting thee same error. Please if anyone can help. here is the error it is displaying.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1165]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Christy>cd "C:\Users\Christy\CSE 632"

C:\Users\Christy\CSE 632>python tweets.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Christy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\Christy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 96, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\Christy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 86, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Christy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\Christy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Christy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Christy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 353, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\Christy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 181, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000013B04320E50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Christy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\Christy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\Christy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stream.twitter.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /1.1/statuses/filter.json?delimited=length (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000013B04320E50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Christy\CSE 632\tweets.py", line 32, in <module>
    stream.filter(track=['Gamestop', 'Robinhood', 'purchase', 'block'])
  File "C:\Users\Christy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 474, in filter
    self._start(is_async)
  File "C:\Users\Christy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 389, in _start
    self._run()
  File "C:\Users\Christy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 320, in _run
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Christy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 719, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Christy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 266, in _run
    resp = self.session.request('POST',
  File "C:\Users\Christy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Christy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Christy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stream.twitter.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /1.1/statuses/filter.json?delimited=length (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000013B04320E50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))

C:\Users\Christy\CSE 632>
```

Comment: Probably can't be solved without a [mcve].

Comment: Maybe there are limitations to the stream.twitter.com that you are trying to maintain a connection.

Comment: Twitter probably blocks your IP, because it detected some bot running. But without the code hard say.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Here is the code:

Comment: from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
access_token = "A"
access_token_secret = "B"
consumer_key = "c"
consumer_secret = "d"
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        print (data)
        return True
    def on_error(self, status):
        print (status)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)
    stream.filter(track=['a'])

Comment: @christyallen please edit your question and add the code in there.  But this is likely a problem at the far end as the comments have pointed out.